# Is this valid RESTful API architecture, and should I really use angular-resource for it?

Tags: angularjs, rest, restful-architecture, angular-resource

First of all: this is strictly for learning purposes, I know I can design my API in any way I like and I don't have to follow the REST architecture to 100%. Okay, so on to the question:

I have a (private) REST(ish?) API that I'm using from an angular app. The API has these endpoints right now:

Session:

```
GET /api/session //Getting the user's session information after a page refresh
DEL /api/session //Logging out
```

User

```
GET /api/user/:id
POST /api/user
DEL /api/user/:id
PUT /api/user/:id

POST /api/user/:id/friendrequest //"Creating" a friendrequest to a user
POST /api/user/:id/groupinvite   //"Creating" a groupinvite to a user
```

Group:

```
GET /api/group/:id
POST /api/group
DELETE /api/group/:id
PUT /api/group/:id

DELETE /api/group/:id/users/:user //Deleting a user from a group
GET /api/group/:id/users          //Get all users in a group

POST /api/group/:id/joinrequest   //"Create" a request to join a group
```

Now I've got a few questions:

I think everything in here should be RESTful, except for 2 things I'm unsure of:

- Is it okay with endpoints that only handle one HTTP verb? For example
  /api/user/:id/friendrequest only handles POSTs, because it shouldn't
  be possible to edit, delete or get all friendrequests.
- /api/session does not take any parameters in the url, because it
  always returns the logged in user's session. I know this breaks the 
  /resource/:id pattern, but I can't see any other way to organize it in 
  which an id would be required.

Also, as you can see, some of these resources are nested, and angular-resource's way of handling nested resources is *really* ugly (or am I doing something wrong?). Is there any reason to not write my own services using $http other than it taking slightly more time and code? I'd rather not use a 3rd party module like RESTangular.

Comment: Looks good to me, except for the session thingy. REST APIs should be stateless, thus not use sessions. You should provide an authentication token that can be cached in your javascript. Check this out: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't actually use (server side) sessions, but provides a JSON web token in a http-only cookie with every request, and the server authenticates it by reading it. The reason for /api/session is to identify the current user and send back its data since the client can't read the http-only cookie. I couldn't think of a better name for it than session (or maybe /api/session/user, but that makes even less sense since session is no resource).

Comment: in our app we use POST api/login and POST api/logoff . In our case we use the webserive to return the token to the client. The client which is developed using Angular then stores the token in browsers storage. The url look good to me .